# REGEX - For Alphanumeric/numeric with potential slash in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a alphanumeric value from a string array using RegEx. Examples:

1. Apartment 101/B First
2. Villa 3324/A Second
3. Milk 12MG/ML Third
4. Sodium 0.00205MG/ML Fourth
5. Water 0.00205MG Fifth
6. Eggs 100 Sixth

My aim is to extract values: 101/B, 3324/A, 12MG/ML, 0.00205MG/ML from the above string arrays. The RegEx I was able to get is something like this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$` which is generic alphanumeric regex.

Comment: Try `text.match(/\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[A-Z])+\/[A-Z0-9]+\b/g)` or `/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*\/[A-Z0-9]+\b/`. In all your examples the slash is obligatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match digits followed by optional chars A-Z and then `/` and  uppercase chars

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*\/[A-Z]+\b
```

- `\b`  A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `[A-Z]*` Match optional chars A-Z
- `\/[A-Z]+` Match `/` and 1+ chars A-Z
  -`\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B0Tprf/1)

```js
const regex = /\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*\/[A-Z]+\b/;
[
  "Apartment 101/B First",
  "Villa 3324/A Second",
  "Milk 12MG/ML Third",
  "Sodium 0.00205MG/ML Fourth",
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0]);
  }
});
```

---

**Edit**

For matching an optional forward slash and also only digit, you can make the part of the pattern optional.

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*(?:\/[A-Z]+)?\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional part
- `[A-Z]*` Match optional uppercase chars A-Z
- `(?:\/[A-Z]+)?` Optionally match `/` and 1+ uppercase chars A-Z
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TRA1kz/1)

Comment: That was way quicker than the time it took for me to post my question. Looks like it's working as expected. Let me run few more tests.

Comment: If I take off the / symbol, I am getting an exception. How to make the Regex to make / as optional?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. the `/` on the left and the right are the delimiters of the regex, they should be there. Else you can use `const regex = new RegExp("\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?[A-Z]*\\/[A-Z]+\\b");` To make the forward slash that is part of the pattern by itself optional, you can use a question mark `\/?`

Comment: My bad, I mean to say, if I remove / from my examples, I am getting an error. For instance, `Milk 15MG Third`

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Then you can use `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*\/?[A-Z]+\b` https://regex101.com/r/C6ijld/1

Comment: How about for the values with just integers? Like this: `Milk 100 Third`

Comment: @ArnoldJr. In that case you can make the second part of the pattern optional `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[A-Z]*\/?[A-Z]+)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/DVFDpu/1 But note that the pattern is becoming a broader match with the added examples, as it matches also only digits now.

Comment: Please update your answer with the final regex. That works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I have added the pattern at the bottom of the answer as an edit.